# Populating TableRow dynamically not working

Tags: java, android, dynamic, tablelayout, tablerow

I was having some problem when trying to populate the `TableRow` dynamically. What I am trying to do is when export button on click, I compile the header, footer and content then once they are done, I proceed to export as PDF.

I populated my `TableLayout` with the following code in compileContent():

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCalibrationList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("DATA" + allCalibrationList.get(i).getCalibrationName());
        TableRow row = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_calibration_report_summary_item, summaryTableLayout, false);
        TextView textCol1 = row.findViewById(R.id.row_col1);
        TextView textCol2 = row.findViewById(R.id.row_col2);

        textCol1.setText(allCalibrationList.get(i).getCalibrationName());
        textCol2.setText(getString(R.string.report_not_calibrated_label));
        
        summaryTableLayout.addView(row);
    }
    contentFinished = true;
```

When my export button on click:

```
@Click(R.id.buttonExport)
void buttonExportClicked(View view) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        while (!headerFinished && !footerFinished && !contentFinished) {
            compileHeader();
            compileContent();
            compileFooter();
        }
        // code to generate pdf
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I first click the export button, it went in the `compileContent()` and from the printed message I put in the for loop, I managed to get the data printed out. However, the `tableRow` is not showing in the exported PDF. The `tableRow` will only show when the export button is clicked the second time.

However, when I click the export button for the second time, it does not went into the `compileContent()` as the printed message I set in for loop is not printing. Why is it so? Why is the `tableRow` is not showing when there is data?

Comment: Why do you use `while`? Do you mean `if` instead? Did you reset `contentFinished` to `false` at anywhere? If not, the `compileContent()` won't run the second time since the condition of the `while` is not satisfied.

Comment: Nope I did not set it to false anywhere because it is supposed to run for one time only. For instance, now when I clicked export button, I managed to get the data but the tableRow is not showing. Then, I clicked the export button for the second time, the tableRow will then be show but the problem is, it does not even went into the compileContent(). So I wonder why the tableRow is not showing the first time?

Comment: Btw, why do you use `while`?

Comment: @RickyMo i thought using while loop will keep it loop until all 3 parts completed? I changed it to if statement the problem still persists

Comment: First of all, `!headerFinished && !footerFinished && !contentFinished` means if any one of the three is finished, the body would not execute, even if the other two are not finished. You probably want `||` instead of `&&`. However, if all of the three compile functions do not contain any asycn call, all of them should always be completed after the first iteration so no point to use a loop.

Comment: Do your compile functions contains any async call? May be the data is not ready when you first generate the PDF? Try printing the data source right before passing it to generate pdf to see what you get.

Comment: @RickyMo Nope it does not work. I changed the && to || and the while loop to if statement but the tableRow is still not populating in the first click :(

Comment: @RickyMo Nope the compileHeader and compileFooter is just setting text to textview. As for the content, I used the for loop posted above to add row dynamically

Comment: According to the code in `buttonExportClicked()` you are (trying to) check whether certain operations are finished (supposedly) before you make a PDF file. But since the code "to generate pdf"  is outside the `while` loop apparently a PDF gets generated every time the button is clicked.. -->  I strongly recommend that you make yourself a flow diagram and rebuild you logic. Take a look at how `if` statements work and what happens when you use   &&  or  ||  logical operators.

Comment: @Barns Yeap that is what I am trying to achieve! Do you have any ideas what am I supposed to change in order to make it works?

Comment: You know your program much better than I, which is why I suggest that you make a flow diagram of how this part of your program should work. Then construct the logical functionality accordingly. Sometimes the flow chart can really be quite helpful. Good luck!

Comment: @RickyMo Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How do you generate your pdf?

Comment: That is a custom class which was not done by me :( I was thinking could it be the logic problem at export button on click?

Comment: better post the part of `// code to generate pdf` to show what data do you pass to that class.

Comment: @RickyMo This is the line: PdfGenerator.generatePdf(headerLayout, contentLayout, footerLayout, fileOutputStream); the headerLayout, contentLayout will be populated in the compileHeader(), compileContent(). I still could not figured out why it has to be two clicks for the tableRow to show

Comment: Have you try checking what does `contentLayout` look like right at this line when it is not working?

Comment: @RickyMo I got other textview in compileContent and they are showing the correct text. Just that the tableRow is not populating on first click :( So I think the problem is with the two chunk of code I posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are doing is updating layouts and convert the layouts to PDF by a custom class. Updating layouts means updating UI, which usually does not complete immediately as UI updates are queued up and will be executed later on UI thread. (That's why when your device is busy and laggy, the UI does not update fast enough)

The `TableRow` you inflate may not be finished when you generate PDF due to how android inflater works. You can use [View.post()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) to run code after the view has finished inflating. Try this:

```
@Click(R.id.buttonExport)
void buttonExportClicked(View view) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        if (!headerFinished || !footerFinished || !contentFinished) {
            compileHeader();
            compileContent();
            compileFooter();
        }
        summaryTableLayout.post(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               // code to generate pdf
           }

        })

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I am trying to! However, after adding the .post I am getting this error message: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.TableLayout.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference

Comment: Is there any way to make it such that the 3 compile functions complete first before generating the pdf?

Comment: How do you initialize `summaryTableLayout`? If it is `null` then `summaryTableLayout.addView(row);` should have thrown the exception before... Would it some how be changed afterwards?

Comment: You may try to replace `summaryTableLayout.post` with `new Handler().post` see if this work around

Comment: I initialized it in the compileContent()!

Comment: Yes. UI updates are automatically posted to the UI thread looper and do not block your current execution. By posting your follow up operation to the UI thread looper, you can ensure your follow up operation is executed after the UI updates are done.